# Mudar o diretório raiz do projeto

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox

Tenho o seguinte arquivo `Vagranfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    # Forward ports to Apache and MySQL
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 8889

    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

Entretanto o diretório onde preciso ter os arquivos `PHP` é `vagrant/src`, porém quero alterar para `/home/filipe/projects/havas/src/`.

Considerando uma instalação do Vagrant 2.0.1, é possível mudar o diretório raiz do projeto?

Answer (score -1):

Tenta mudar a **sincronização da pasta**, usando a propriedade `synced_folder` assim como exemplo a seguir:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"
```

**[Documentação](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html)**

Comment: Obrigado. Eu fiz isso, mas não funcionou. O 1º parâmetro é o diretorio relativo ao host e o segundo em relação ao guest. Então entrei na maquina virtual via ssh e editei o `DocumentRoot` do VirtualHost, que não estava a ser atualizado (isso não deveria ser automático?) no momento em que o comando `vagrant up` era executado. Reiniciei o serviço do Apache e tudo ficou a funcionar. Só não percebo porque foi necessário editar o `DocumentRoot` manualmente.